# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to do one-to-many mapping in hibernate,but it is showing exception,I tried a lot but unable to find solution

I have below two tables

### dept

deptno -- number primary key 
dname -- varchar2(10) 
loc -- varchar2(10)

### employee1

empno -- number primary key 
username -- varchar2(10)
deptno -- number(10) foreign key

when I am not adding @Entity annotation on Dept.java class I am getting below stacktrace

```
21:35:11.554 [main] DEBUG o.h.i.f.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [enhanced-table] -> [class org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator]
21:35:11.554 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
21:35:11.554 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
21:35:11.632 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - trying to resolve system-id [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd]
21:35:11.632 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
21:35:11.632 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
21:35:11.632 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - located [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd] in classpath
21:35:11.663 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
21:35:11.663 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
21:35:11.663 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - hibernate.connection.username=test
21:35:11.663 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - hibernate.connection.password=test
21:35:11.663 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
21:35:11.663 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - session-factory config [null] named class [com.beans.Employee] for mapping
21:35:11.663 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - session-factory config [null] named class [com.beans.Dept] for mapping
21:35:11.663 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
21:35:11.663 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - properties: {hibernate.connection.password=test, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\bin, java.vm.version=23.7-b01, hibernate.connection.username=test, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, path.separator=;, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, user.script=, user.country=US, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, sun.os.patch.level=, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, user.dir=E:\javahyd\eclipse_new_hibernate\One_Many1, java.runtime.version=1.7.0_17-b02, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment, java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\endorsed, os.arch=amd64, java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\rajeev\AppData\Local\Temp\, line.separator=
, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, user.variant=, os.name=Windows 7, sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252, java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\SERVER\BIN;.;.;C:\PROGRAM FILES\MYSQL\MYSQL SERVER 5.5\BIN;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;C:\Windows\System32;.;E:\sts\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.0.M1;;., java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=51.0, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, os.version=6.1, user.home=C:\Users\rajeev, user.timezone=Asia/Calcutta, java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob, file.encoding=Cp1252, java.specification.version=1.7, hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, java.class.path=E:\javahyd\eclipse_new_hibernate\One_Many1\target\classes;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\annotations-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\catalina-ant.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\catalina-ha.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\catalina-tribes.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\catalina.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\ecj-3.7.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\el-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jasper-el.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jasper.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\tomcat-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\tomcat-coyote.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\tomcat-dbcp.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\tomcat-i18n-es.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\tomcat-i18n-fr.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\tomcat-i18n-ja.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\tomcat-jdbc.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\tomcat-util.jar;C:\Users\rajeev\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.2\logback-core-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeev\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.2\logback-classic-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeev\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.6\slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar;C:\Users\rajeev\.m2\repository\com\myoracle\ojdbc14\10.2.0.1.0\ojdbc14-10.2.0.1.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeev\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\3.6.10.Final\hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\rajeev\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.6\antlr-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\rajeev\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.1\commons-collections-3.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeev\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeev\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-commons-annotations\3.2.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\rajeev\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\rajeev\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeev\.m2\repository\javassist\javassist\3.12.1.GA\javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar, user.name=rajeev, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, java.vm.specification.version=1.7, sun.java.command=com.test.Test, java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre, sun.arch.data.model=64, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE, user.language=en, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit, java.vm.info=mixed mode, java.version=1.7.0_17, java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext, sun.boot.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\classes, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, file.separator=\, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, sun.cpu.endian=little, sun.desktop=windows, sun.cpu.isalist=amd64}
21:35:11.663 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Preparing to build session factory with filters : {}
21:35:11.741 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Processing hbm.xml files
21:35:11.741 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Process annotated classes
21:35:11.756 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.beans.Employee
21:35:11.789 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3DiscriminatorColumn{logicalColumnName'DTYPE', discriminatorTypeName='string'}
21:35:11.804 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - no value specified for 'javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode'; using UNSPECIFIED
21:35:11.820 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Import with entity name Employee
21:35:11.820 [main] INFO  o.h.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.beans.Employee on table employee1
21:35:11.867 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(employee1), mappingColumn=empno, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
21:35:11.882 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - binding property empno with lazy=false
21:35:11.882 [main] DEBUG o.h.c.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - building SimpleValue for empno
21:35:11.882 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Building property empno
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3JoinColumn{logicalColumnName='deptno', referencedColumn='', mappedBy=''}
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(employee1), mappingColumn=dept, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Building property dept
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(employee1), mappingColumn=deptno, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - binding property deptno with lazy=false
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG o.h.c.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - building SimpleValue for deptno
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Building property deptno
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(employee1), mappingColumn=userName, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - binding property userName with lazy=false
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG o.h.c.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - building SimpleValue for userName
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Building property userName
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG o.h.c.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - Setting SimpleValue typeName for empno
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG o.h.c.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - Setting SimpleValue typeName for deptno
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG o.h.c.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - Setting SimpleValue typeName for userName
21:35:11.898 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - processing fk mappings (*ToOne and JoinedSubclass)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.beans.Employee.dept references an unknown entity: com.beans.Dept
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1580)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1503)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1419)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1856)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

when I am adding @Entity annotation on Dept.java class I am getting below stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.beans.Employee column: deptno (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:676)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:698)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1865)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <mapping class="com.beans.Employee"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.beans.Dept"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

### Dept.java

```
package com.beans;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Dept {
    @Id
    private int deptno;

    private String dname;

    private String loc;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dept")
    Set<Employee> set;

    public Set<Employee> getSet() {
        return set;
    }

    public void setSet(Set<Employee> set) {
        this.set = set;
    }

    public int getDeptno() {
        return deptno;
    }

    public void setDeptno(int deptno) {
        this.deptno = deptno;
    }

    public String getDname() {
        return dname;
    }

    public void setDname(String dname) {
        this.dname = dname;
    }

    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

}
```

### Employee.java

```
package com.beans;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee1")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private int empno;

    private String userName;

    private int deptno;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "deptno")
    private Dept dept;

    public Dept getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public void setDept(Dept dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    public int getEmpno() {
        return empno;
    }

    public void setEmpno(int empno) {
        this.empno = empno;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public int getDeptno() {
        return deptno;
    }

    public void setDeptno(int deptno) {
        this.deptno = deptno;
    }

}
```

### Test.java

```
package com.test;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.beans.Dept;
import com.beans.Employee;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        Dept dept = new Dept();
        Set<Employee> set = new HashSet<Employee>();
        set.add(employee);

        dept.setDeptno(11);
        dept.setDname("mca");
        dept.setLoc("sbp");
        dept.setSet(set);
        session.save(dept);

        employee.setEmpno(1);
        employee.setUserName("rajeev");
        employee.setDept(dept);
        session.save(employee);

        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

can anyone help me to find the mistake...
below is the githib link 
git@github.com:mcarajeev/hibernate3.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Employee.java you have added `deptno` as a join column and you have already added `deptno` as column so it is creating two `deptno` in same table which is giving Exception.

Solution : You can remove `private int deptno` from Employee.java as your Join column will work as foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the entities, this exception should not be thrown, however when I checked code on git, @Entity annotation is missing on Dept class, are you sure that you are using @Entity?

Note that this exception is thrown when you map an entity about which hibernate is not aware off. Like in your case, Employee has association with Dept but Dept is not known to hibernate as an entity as you have not used @Entity.

```
private int deptno;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "deptno")
private Dept dept;
```

Remove `private int deptno`, hibernate will generate it as a part of association.